# If statements in SCSS using CSS variables

Tags: css, sass

My JS code sets a variable on the page:

```js
  if (error) {
    document.querySelector('body')?.style.setProperty('--pickererror', `'${ error }'`);
  }
```

My SCSS code uses that variable for some content:

```
  $error: var(--pickererror);

  // ERROR MESSAGE
  .picker-toolbar::before {
    content: $error;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px 35px 0px 35px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .picker-toolbar {
    @if str-length($error) > 0 {
      order: 1 !important;
    }
  }
```

The `::before` section works completely. However the `@if` clause executes even if there is no error, and the `.picker-toolbar` is always at `order: 1`.

I have checked that `--pickererror` is not present when there's no JS error. I've tried any number of permutations, such as

1. Putting the `@if` line before the `.picker-toolbar` line
2. Simply using `@if $error`
3. Using `@if var(--pickererror)` in place of the `$error` variable.

How do I make this work?

Comment: I could be wrong on this but I don't think that `@if` is getting evaluated at runtime when the custom property `--pickererror` changes. I think you'd be better off applying a second class to whatever element has the `.picker-toolbar` to change the order.

Comment: Sass is precompiled so that if won't exists in the actual css the site uses, why not just use the js to add a class to any picker toolbars that have an error

Comment: All the `.picker-xxx` elements are managed by a 3rd party component, in my React code. I've been having trouble getting refs which I suppose is what I'd need to add classes and things like that. Sounds like that's the only possible route though?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code specific to rendering the picker, then I would agree with your statement about the refs (or maybe that component/library has some API or renderProps to tie into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you remove the logic from your stylesheet entirely, and instead rely on the dynamic property value from your JavaScript?

For example:

```
body {
  --pickererror: 0; // Default value for the "order" property
}
```

If your JavaScript detects an error, the `--pickererror` is given a value of `1 !important`;

```js
if (error) {
  document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--pickererror', '1', 'important');
}
```

And in your stylesheet, you only need a single rule that changes the order if the JavaScript says so.

```
.picker-toolbar {
  order: var(--pickererror, 0); // Defaults to "0" also if the variable doesn't exist
}
```

I realize this only makes sense if you are using `--pickererror` mostly as a boolean (I thought since you're checking if its length is greater than 0). If you're actually using the string value, it would be better to create an `--error-order` variable for this single purpose I guess.

Comment: That is a great idea, and I'm sure it will work, and I'll mark it as the answer. I may not use it, because it seems to violate separation of concerns, putting all that styling info in the JS instead of just the logic that dictates it. Thanks!